# How to autoresize a view controller so that it's view starts below the status bar?

Tags: iphone

I have a UIViewController which creates it's own view. It's a fullscreen image at 320 x 460 size. But for some reason that image seems to be placed below the status bar. I guess I could set some autoresize mask, so that this view is automatically placed below the status bar? (I mean not exactly below, but 20px down... so not covered...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the alignment controller and make your controller stick to the bottom of the view I steed of the top